# Application Privilege Control in Kaspersky blocks program with no digital signature

Tags: malware, digital-signature, antivirus

I made a small application that displays hello world to the console output and attempted to open it in another computer that had Kaspersky fully updated. When I ran the application, Kaspersky gave a message about Application Privilege Control and the hello world application not having a digital signature so it wasn't trusted.

Zeus botnet seems to have infected millions of computers, does it have a digital signature that Kaspersky doesn't detect the virus or does it simply bypass the antivirus software?

This is the message that pops up.

[image: Kaspersky warning message]

Comment: Generally the point of malware is to gain execution through non-standard means.  The digital signature check is probably just an initial protection against simple attacks.  Kaspersky detects and protects its users against Zeus according to this post: http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=180597&view=findpost&p=1441367

Comment: if that's the case then zeus can't run on computers that have kaspersky installed if i'm not wrong.

Comment: As that poster stated there are many variants and no antivirus is going to catch 100% of malicious code.  It can most likely run just fine, but Kaspersky can detect and remove it.

Comment: so if the digital signature of the application is not verified, the message will always pop up? and is it possible for malware to simply put a legit digital signature taken from a legit software?

Comment: I'm really not sure what Kaspersky is looking for with regards to signature verification.

Comment: I posted the screenshot of the message.